# How do you unlock each of the stages?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

I've managed to unlock one stage (Towerforge) by playing through the entirety of Quest mode.

A friend has told me that he got one randomly by selecting random in the stage selection, and another by the end of a versus match on a specific stage.

What are the definite ways to unlock these stages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll update this answer as I unlock stages:

- **Sunken City**: Choose "random" at the versus mode stage selection, it will come up eventually.
- **Towerforge**: Beat King's Court in Quest mode on any difficulty.
- **Moonstone**: Play a match on every non-unlockable level in versus mode, then play a match on Sacred Ground.
- **Ascension**: After unlocking the previous 3 levels, go to archives and find the Ascension tab. On each of the 3 stages you can find hidden direction symbols in the background which make a code you can input.

  - Final code: <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> - <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> -  <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Quest Mode-only Stages:

- **Gauntlet**: Beat Ascension in Quest mode.
- **Gauntlet II**: Beat every level in Quest mode on hardcore difficulty.

Comment: And the Gauntlet unlocked for me after beating Ascension.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any Gauntlet III.

Comment: @Lunfel I have no idea how that got there, nor how it stayed there so long.

Answer (score 0):

By Beating Ascension you unlock a stage called Gauntlet. Instead of stages in Quest mode it has a set number of enemies that spawn roughly 10 at a time in the beginning and slowly becomes tougher and more numerous enemies in the "waves". I beat Gauntlet and have not unlocked anything after that, I know for a fact that there is one more stage, I'm assuming I need to finish more missions on hardcore mode to unlock it. I do currently have 13 out of the 14 white skulls and 4 out 14 red ones.

Comment: You do need to finish everything on hardcore. It's crazy.

Comment: Challenge accepted. Wish me luck.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the background of the basic levels for a hint to unlock the level. Remember, the level is called Moonstone.

We unlocked everything this afternoon, just played a random versus match on the level and it unlocked it.

The other level we got by selecting random level and it showed up for us.

Comment: Yes, I know now which level spawns it, just spawning it is the tough part.